# How to reset value of properties in object?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have custom type object:

```
export interface IPupilFilter {
  Fullname: string;
  Gender: string;
  ClassType: number;
  Language: number;
  Class: number;
  ClassNumber: number;
  Phone: string;
  Movement: string;
}
public requestLoadPupils: IPupilFilter = <IPupilFilter>{};
```

During process of filling form this object is filled corresponding interface.

How to reset all value properties and set to null?

I tried:

```
this.requestLoadPupils = <IPupilFilter>{} as IPupilFilter;
```

I can reset each property like: `this.requestLoadPupils.Gender = null;` But I dont like that

Comment: I can reset each property like: `this.requestLoadPupils.Gender = null`; But I dont like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [Partial](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6) for this.

```
public requestLoadPupils: Partial<IPupilFilter> = {};
```

And then you can just clear the object by assigned it to a new empty object.

```
this.requestLoadPupils = {};
```

Then when you're absolutely sure that the form has been completely filled out, you can cast it back to a full `IPupilFilter`.

```
const pupilFilter = this.requestLoadPupils as IPupilFilter;
```

When you wrap an interface with Partial, it's basically the equivalent of making all the items optional.  So

```
type PartialIPupilFilter = Partial<IPupilFilter>
```

Is the same as:

```
interface PartialIPupilFilter {
  Fullname?: string;
  Gender?: string;
  ClassType?: number;
  Language?: number;
  Class?: number;
  ClassNumber?: number;
  Phone?: string;
  Movement?: string;
}
```

All elements are still typed, but you are not required to set them on instantiation.

Comment: Interesting approach

Comment: Shoud I import something for using: `Partial`?

Comment: @OPV: No.  It's a type in Typescript since 2.1 (I think).  There are quite a few helpful types.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Partial only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: Sorry is is my bad, I tried to do that in wrong place

Comment: `requestLoadPupils` should be of type `Partial<IPupilFilter>` because not all attributes can be guaranteed to be set.

Comment: Please edit this: `this.requestLoadPupils: Partial<IPupilFilter>;` on `public requestLoadPupils: Partial<IPupilFilter>;`

Comment: Better: `public requestLoadPupils: Partial<IPupilFilter> = {};`

Comment: When I try to reset using this: `this.requestLoadPupils = {};` It leaves properties values

Comment: Also I  tried reset as: `this.requestLoadPupils = {} as IPupilFilter;`

Comment: What about: `this.requestLoadPupils = Object.assign({}, <IPupilFilter>{});`?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?  I guarantee you can assign empty objects to Partial types. It's just Javascript underneath, so if you still see attributes after assigned an empty object then it's because they're being set somewhere.